# PHP - Multiple MySQL result, in separate variables

Tags: php, mysql, rows

I need to do a MySQL query to search for an inexact match / match containing the submitted value.

The following is an example of what is in my database:

```
id               img
1          1001_ABC_01.jpg
2          1001_ABC_02.jpg
3          1002_ABC_01.jpg
4          1002_ABC_02.jpg
5          1002_ABC_03.jpg
6          1002_ABC_04.jpg
7          1002_ABC_05.jpg
8          1003_ABC_01.jpg
9          1003_ABC_02.jpg
10         1003_ABC_03.jpg
```

I need the query to search for the first part of the filename (`1002`) and and assign each returned result in the img field a different variable. The maximum amount of variables would be 5.

For example, if I search `1002`, it should assign the following variables:

```
    <?php
    $img1 = '1002_ABC_01.jpg';
    $img2 = '1002_ABC_02.jpg';
    $img3 = '1002_ABC_03.jpg';
    $img4 = '1002_ABC_04.jpg';
    $img5 = '1002_ABC_05.jpg';
    ?>
```

so that way I can echo each filename result individually.

Again, the maximum amount of variables here will be 5, so if more than 5 results are returned, only the first 5 will be assigned variables.

Please let me know if this is possible and how to write a PHP script to do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT img FROM <table_name> WHERE img LIKE '%search%' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 5;
```

You could `substring` function, if the first four integers are fixed like this:

```
select substring(img,1,4) from <table_name> where img = 'search' order by ID DESC limit 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you. Always try to use latest apis and function like **MySqli** try to avoid **mysql_*** functions because they are depreciated and MySqli is also faster then mysql_ functions

```
$img = '1002'; // For example
$connection = new Mysqli(host, user, password, database);
$sql = "SELECT img FROM <table_name> WHERE img LIKE '$img%' LIMIT 5";

if($connection->query($sql)){
    $counter = 1;
    while ($row = $connection->fetch_object()){
        ${'img'.$counter} = $row->img;
        $counter++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE img_name LIKE '%1002%' LIMIT 5";

foreach ( $fetched_row as $value ) {
  echo $value [ 'img_name' ]; // or whatever you want to do
}
```

Something like that.

Answer (score 0):

**your code will look like this:**

```
$input = '1002'; // For example
$query = "SELECT id, img FROM table_blah WHERE img LIKE '$input%' LIMIT 5";
```

This query is basically **selecting** id, and img **from** the table `table_blah`, and `img` must be the same as 1002, and `%` meaning absolutely anything from there on. **Limited** to 5 results.

**Then:**

```
$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // Code for each result here.
    // id = $row['id']
    // img = $row['img']
}
```

Comment: jared : yours look kinda like it does what i want, almost... the problem is that it is multiple results from the same field in the database...

Comment: run this exact code, and replace the commented code with: `echo "id: {$row['id']} img: {$row['img']}";`  You will find it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this query

```
SELECT img as IMG
FROM my_table
WHERE img LIKE '1002%'
order by id desc
LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $query="SELECT id,img as image FROM image_table 
  where img like '%$keyword%' limit 5";
  $res=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
  while ($img = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    echo $img['image'];
  }
?>
```

Comment: Your code contains SQL injection (or at least has potential for one). Also, please stop recommending other `mysql_*` function, they are no longer maintained and community has begun deprecation process. You should start writing code with either PDO or MySQLi APIs and prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
$con = new Mysqli(host, user, password, database);
$result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE image LIKE %$search% ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5");
if($result){
    while ($row = $con->fetch_object()){
        $img_arr[] = $row;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you.

```
$queryStr = "SELECT img FROM table_name WHERE search_str LIKE '1002%'";
$query = mysql_query($queryStr);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $imageArray[] = $row;   
}

// Print the array
echo '<pre>';
print_r($imageArray);
echo '</pre>';

// How to use the array
foreach($imageArray as $key=>$val){
    echo 'File Name: '.$val;
    echo '<br />';
    echo '<img src="'.$val.'" />';  
    echo '<hr />';
}

// Now show first five result
    // Alternet: You can use LIMIT and order by with mysql
// With php
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
    echo 'File Name: '.$imageArray[$i];
    echo '<br />';
    echo '<img src="'.$imageArray[$i].'" />';   
    echo '<hr />';  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To search for a partial match you can use the `LIKE` operator in SQL. In this case you could write:

```
$sql = "SELECT img FROM tablename WHERE img like '1002%'";
```

How to perform this query and obtain the results in PHP depends on the database API you are using: old MySQL? MySQLi? PDO? Also, `1002` is probably user input, in which case you have to protect your program against SQL injection attacks.

As to the second part, are you sure you want different variable names and not an array? Arrays are much easier to use. You can get different variable names if you first accumulate the data in an array and then use [`extract`](http://es.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php):

```
$result = array();
$counter = 1;
$rs = mysql_query($sql); // using old mysql API

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
    $result["img".$counter] =  $row[0];
    $counter = $counter + 1;
}

extract($result);
// now $img1, $img2, $img3, ... are defined
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     $query = "SELECT * FROM img_table WHERE img_name regexp concat('1002', '%')"
     $results = mysql_query($query);
```

then $results is an array of img strings